# pstool not working with grffile

Tags: errors, input, pstool

An error report regarding my template and pstool not working made me look at the problem which 
seems to be a principle problem of pstool together with grffile

I created a matlabfraq file using

```
figure(1), clf;
plot([1 2]);
ylabel('A straight line');
matlabfrag('testpic');
```

(can I attach these files here?)

If I load this using the following code

```
\documentclass{minimal}
\usepackage[extendedchars, encoding, multidot, space,filenameencoding=latin1]{grffile}
\usepackage[crop=pdfcrop]{pstool}

\begin{document}
\psfragfig*{images/pstool/testpic}{}
\end{document}
```

it fails because of `grffile`. In the file `testpic-pstool.tex` the code

```
\csname @input\endcsname {images/pstool/testpic.tex}
 \includegraphics [] {testpic}
```

fails with

```
Package grffile Info: \Gin@ii of package `graphicx' fixed on input line 15.
(./images/pstool/testpic.tex)

! LaTeX Error: File `testpic' not found.
```

What is causing this error?

Comment: There is no way to upload the files here. The best thing to do is upload them to an external site and add a link to your question.

Comment: Any suggestion for a free upload site without registration. I do not mind if the files are deleted in a few weeks.